# MYSQL get a list of any users email address that has not done something

Tags: mysql

So this one has me puzzled a little. I am not sure if it can even be done.

So each week i require users to send me some details via a form ( a report to me ). That form stamps a date in the database table and marks the row saying received as yes along with a user_id field.

What i wanted to do, is once a week get all reports submitted within 7 days using a cron job, which i can do using this:

```
SELECT * FROM nfw_weekly_report WHERE record_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

What i want to do though, is using the user_id in that list compare it with the "users" table and grab the name and email address of ALL USERS that DID NOT send me their weekly report so i can in turn email them all.

Is there a mysql query that can do that? Grab all entries between 7 days as i listed above, then grab all users from the users table that did not submit one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.name, u.email
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN nfw_weekly_report r ON u.id = r.user_id
                             AND r.record_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
WHERE r.user_id is null
```

Comment: i cant vote due to being new but this was a great answer. Thank you Juergen. it worked  ;)